# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.forms.util'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django model class which have a field of 'amount' I used `pip install django-moneyfield` install money field but I got an error when I run migration

My Code:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fee = MoneyField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 8,
                             amount_default = Decimal("0"),
                             currency_default = "INR", 
                             null = True, blank = True)
```

Error
[image: Error]

Comment: Just curious, which IDE is this?

Comment: What is your Django  version?

Comment: @ilyasbbu it is PyCharm IDE

Comment: @ilyasbbu yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

the module `django.forms.util` is an old module of django which has been renamed after django 1.7 in `django.forms.utils`

django-moneyfield is an old django module which is not maintenand from 2017. I think you can replaced it by [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) which is up-to-date

Comment: I still get that error

Comment: it is not possible, django-money does not contains line **import django.forms.util**. You have just install without uninstall old package and replace your model field from django-money field

Answer (score 0):

the last release for `django-moneyfield` package is in 2013.

> Moneyfield requires:
>
> Python ==3.3
>
> Django ==1.5 (still working on 1.6 compatibility)

You can research an alternative package it seems this package is not supported anymore. You can use [DjangoMoney](https://pypi.org/project/django-money/) instead.